# Are there any museums or sites in England honouring Isambard Kingdom Brunel?

Tags: museums, england, geek-travel, science

I'm travelling to the UK from Australia and wanted to visit a number of sites of scientific history.

One at the top of my list is Isambard Kingdom Brunel.

I understand there are [10 surviving structures](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/picturegalleries/5925618/Top-10-Isambard-Kingdom-Brunels-great-surviving-structures.html) you can visit. I know you can visit [his ship in Bristol](http://www.traveleditions.co.uk/tour/Bristol-and-the-Brunel-Legacy) - the SS Great Britain.

But can you visit a museum with a display about his life and works?

My question is: **Are there any museums or sites in England honouring Isambard Kingdom Brunel?**

Comment: At the SS Great Britain in Bristol there is also a museum which is obviously mostly about the ship, but also has plenty of information on Brunel himself (I think - I last visited as a child...). Also looks like they're building a Brunel museum in Bristol, but it's not open yet.

Comment: Brunel University in Uxbridge, West London has a couple statues of the man himself and some historic explanations here and there.

Comment: I think he's mentioned at the National Railway Museum (which is really worth a visit if you like trains, and is free)

Comment: There's a lot more than 10 surviving structures - those are just the Telegraph's "10 best"

Comment: The city of Bristol seems to have adopted Brunel as a local hero. As well as the SS Great Britain, there is the Clifton suspension bridge and Temple Meads station - and the so-called Brunel Mile walk between the station and the ship. There are plaques and homages throughout the city. Not quite an open air museum but not far off. The bridge also has a small museum showcasing its construction and its creators.

Comment: If you are in Wales then here is one structure:
[https://www.stayinwales.co.uk/wales_picture.cfm?p=4142](https://www.stayinwales.co.uk/wales_picture.cfm?p=4142)

Comment: Here's the link to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isambard_Kingdom_Brunel

Comment: My favourite Brunel fan, @SydneyPadua on Twitter, endorses the answers below, saying they "mention the 3 I would- GWR museum in Swindon, the Great Eastern in Bristol, and the cute little one in Rotherhithe!"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Very near the site of the "Oldest Tunnel in the Oldest Underground in the World", in Rotherhithe in south east London, you can find the [Brunel Museum](http://www.brunel-museum.org.uk/), which, well, is not just 'a display' about his life and works, but **an entire museum** about his life and works.

> The Brunel Museum is open every day 10:00 until 17:00.
>
> [...]
>
> Entry to the Brunel Museum is £6 and £4 for concessions. Children
>   under 16 accompanied by parent or carer enter free of charge. Entry to
>   Great Eastern launch ramps is free.
>
> Brunel Museum  Railway Avenue  Rotherhithe  London, SE16 4LF
>
> Telephone: +44 20 7231 3840  Email: info@brunel-museum.org.uk

Comment: This museum is very nice, but it's worth mentioning it's quite small and is focused mainly on Brunel's early work particularly on the Thames Tunnel (which they occassionally have walking tours of). Isambard's father led on this, not Isambard himself, and I seem to remember the museum felt very much curated by someone who preferred Brunel Senior's work to that of his more famous son! Definitely worth a visit though

Comment: The ["Museum of the Great Western Railway" in Swindon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_of_the_Great_Western_Railway), despite not having "Brunel" in its name, might have more on some of the works Isambard is more famous for (I've not been, but it's described as telling his story). They even had [an opera about him last year](http://www.steam-museum.org.uk/events/Pages/Brunel-The-Opera.aspx)...

Answer (score 15):

In terms of a comprehensive museum, not yet.

However, if you are travelling in 2018 (or reading this reply in the future) then there will be a new museum called 'Being Brunel: the national Brunel project' opening in Bristol in a year's time.

> The ss Great Britain Trust has today been awarded £4.78m by the
>   Heritage Lottery Fund (HLF) for Being Brunel: the national Brunel
>   project. The new museum, set to open in Bristol early 2018, will
>   celebrate and explore Brunel, one of the world’s greatest engineers
>   and designers.
>
> The attraction will feature galleries and interactive experiences set
>   in reconstructed buildings that reflect the original Victorian
>   waterfront panorama. Brunel’s Drawing Office, a Grade II listed
>   building, will be restored to become part of the new museum. [Link](http://www.ssgreatbritain.org/about-us/press/new-brunel-museum-confirmed-major-funding-award)

You can read more about the project here: http://www.ssgreatbritain.org/about-us/being-brunel

Answer (score 7):

@jl6's point in the comments is a good one, but deserves to be expanded upon (Brunel has been adopted as a local hero in Bristol). He's one of the few historical figures we've got who didn't directly get rich from the slave trade).  See for example [Isambard Kingdom Brunel, famous engineer and his work at Bristol (local tourism/history site)](https://www.about-bristol.co.uk/fam-01.asp) for a few more things to spot on the way between the main sites. **The bridge has a [visitor centre/small museum and tours](https://www.cliftonbridge.org.uk/visit)**,  but unfortunately the limited [tours of the vaults below the tower](https://www.cliftonbridge.org.uk/event/hard-hat-tour-leigh-woods-abutment-3) are mostly sold out this year.

Some of the best views of the bridge are from the western tip of Spike Island, only a mile on foot from the SS Great Britain.  Trains from London via Bath bring you into Brunel's [Temple Meads station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_Temple_Meads_railway_station) along Brunel's [GWR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Western_Railway), but you may want to take stopping services to see some of the [key features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Western_Railway#Engineering_features) along the way.

Answer (score 5):

You can see what items of the Science Museum's collection are on display, and in which museums, using their collection search. Putting in "Brunel" gets a few results, presumably as part of exhibits that discuss the man further.

http://collection.sciencemuseum.org.uk/search?q=brunel

Answer (score 4):

In Swindon, you can find the [museum of the Great Western Railway](http://www.steam-museum.org.uk/Pages/Home.aspx) of whom Brunel was a chief engineer. As well as the story of the railway itself, it tells the story of how society thanks to the railway, and of Brunel's key role in the whole enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the worlds oldest Wrought Iron railway bridge still in use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windsor_Railway_Bridge